# Problem in sending an email in android

Tags: android

I have a query. In my application, on click of a button, I start an intent to send email. I have set the "To" list, "Subject" and attachment in my coding. Now my problem is that when the email screen is shown, user should not be able modify the email contents nor should he be allowed to remove the attachment. Only he sould be able to click on "Send" button. Please help me out in this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't use the Intent then, by using the Intent, you are forced to follow the rules of the other application, as `CommonsWare` wrote, implement your own SMTP engine. :)

Answer (score 0):

> user should not be able modify the
>   email contents nor should he be
>   allowed to remove the attachment.

The user can do whatever the user wants. It is the user's device. It is the user's email account.

If you wish to force the email to be unmodified, you will have to send the email directly via SMTP, collecting email account information from the user.